# PHP/AJAX login form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a login form wrapped in a Bootstrap modal it looks like this.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Logga in</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

<form action="login.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword1" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Lösenord</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Lösenord">
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Register</button>
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
</div>
```

Currently on login I get redirected to login.php when i submit the form, instead of this I would like to do the check before leaving the site with the modal open. And any errors should be displayed inside the modal.

Here's login.php.

```
<?php include 'includes/core/head.php' ?>
<div class="fold">
<?php include 'includes/core/header.php' ?>
<div class="container">
<?php
if(empty($_POST) === false) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];

    if(empty($email) || empty($password)) {
        $errors[] = 'All fields required.';
    } else if(user_exists($email) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Email not registered.';
    } else if(user_active($email) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Eposten not activated.';
    } else {
        $login = login($email, $password);
        if ($login === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Wrong email or password.';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
            header('Location: site.php');
            exit();
        }
    }

    print_r($errors);
}
?>
</div> <!-- /.fold.container -->
</div>
<?php include 'includes/core/footer.php' ?>
```

I understand that the solution is AJAX, but I've never used it. How do I connect the login form to login.php with a js call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you'll need to use JavaScript to intercept the form post and perform the logic using AJAX.  So you could start off by intercepting the click event for the submit button:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function (e) {
    // This is where the AJAX logic would go
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

So far all this is doing is intercepting the click event for the button and preventing it from submitting the form.  If there are other submit buttons in other forms on the page then you'll want to use an `id` or some other way to uniquely identify this one in the jQuery selector, of course.

Once you've intercepted the form post, you can then manually post it using an AJAX call.  Something like this:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function (e) {

    $.post('login.php', $('form').serialize())
    .done(function(data) {
        // There is where you handle the response
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This updated code is doing a couple of things.  It's serializing the data from the form (again, use a more specific selector if there are or could potentially be more form elements) and it's sending that data in a POST request to `login.php`.  Then it's using the `.done()` function as a callback for the response from that AJAX request.

From the perspective of the server-side code in `login.php` there's essentially no difference.  It's going to respond to this AJAX request exactly as it would a normal post.  So this is where you're going to have to make some changes, because currently it looks like `login.php` performs a redirect after successful login.  And you don't redirect through an AJAX response.

So at this point you'll need to determine how you want the system to behave for your AJAX login.  I recommend that you post to a different server-side resource which returns JSON data instead of a redirect or a page, and then `data` in that callback function would just contain that resulting data.  That would make it easier to respond to it in the JavaScript code.  (It could display an error message, update some page content, do a client-side redirect, etc.)

Comment: Great answer, and I get everything except the last paragraph. Could you maybe give an example how my $errors array could be sent back as a javascript array (or similar) instead of php? From there I should be fine.

Comment: @hustlerinc: I believe PHP has a built-in function for converting values into JSON strings: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php  All you should need to do is JSON-encode the array and echo it to the output.  (The output should be just JSON data, no HTML.)  Then the `data` value client-side would be that JSON data, and you could access it like any JavaScript value.  So if `data` is an array of strings, you can iterate over it and display those strings to the user.

Answer (score 0):

See [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for a complete library and docs on the subject.

Exact implementation depends on exactly what you want to do.
Probably, you will also want to use [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) (or one of its siblings) to arrange the data you want to submit.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand what does ajax do. Here is an example from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_post).

In this example, the html page makes a simple post with 2 parameters to [demo_test_post.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_test_post.asp). 
On return, demo_test_post.asp returns a string back to jquery ajax and it displays the string.

A brief explanation about ajax HTTP POST you can read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp).

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
  {
     name:"Donald Duck",
     city:"Duckburg"
  },
  function(data,status){
     alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
});
```

If you need more details of what is jquery ajax you can refer to jquery doc page [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to to your head

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $('#form1').serialize(),
                    url: "login.php",
                    success: function (msg) {
                      alert(msg);
                    }

                });
            });
    });
</script>
```

and your edited html is

### html

```
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Logga in</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

<form action="login.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id='form1'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword1" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Lösenord</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Lösenord">
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Register</button>
<input type="button" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" id='submit'>
</form>
</div>
```

### login.php

```
<?php
$data=$_POST['serialize'];
$email = $data['email'];
$password= $data['password'];

?>
```